# What is the correct way of using a Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, object, coding-style, dictionary

I have (lots of) objects `Foo` with an unique `ID` and want to store these in a `Dictionary`. The dictionary key in C# can be any primitive type or object. I could use the integer `foo1.ID` as key but also the object `foo1`.

Which is the correct way of implementing that and is there a difference in performance using either the `ID` (an integer) or the object as key?

NB. The values in the dictionary are other (type of) of objects.

Comment: Why use a dictionary at all for this?

Comment: [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and [KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) may be of interest.

Comment: The goal is to retrieve the value in O(1). When searching the dictionary I have the Object (not only the ID). I was wondering if there is a best practise.

Comment: @Oosterman: If you have the object already, what are you searching for? If you just need to verify that the object is in set use a `HashSet<T>` instead.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear - is this some sort of "I have a `Foo` - but is it the 'canonical' `Foo` with this identity?"

Comment: Oke, new try :P. I have (many) objects of type A and want to link them to objects of type B. Each A is linked to at most one B. When searching I have the whole object A (not only the ID). What is the best practise in that case: use the id of A as key or the complete object A?

Comment: Re: your edit - that was a *very important* piece of information you left out. Generally, when people talk about storing `X` in a dictionary, they're talking about the *values*, **not** the keys.

Comment: Ah, that was where the confusion came from. Apologies, I'll try to be more complete in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you intend to *search* the dictionary? If you intend to search for items within the dictionary based purely on `ID`, then use that as the key. OTOH, if you're going to have an instance of a `Foo`, then make that the key.

---

Re: your edit - now we know that the `Foo` is either "the key" or "the object that provides the key value by accessing a property", then it seems simple to say, use a `Dictionary<Foo,OtherClass>` - assuming you've set up equality comparisons on `Foo` objects appropriately - why force every instance of lookup to know to extract a specific property from the `Foo` objects?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case. Assuming you want to look up objects *given their key value* you of course want the id to be the key. That you are asking this question makes me think maybe you don't want a dictionary at all - if you just need to keep a collection of items use a `List<T>` instead - dictionaries are for mapping a key (e.g. an id) to a value (e.g. a custom object).

Comment: I might have not been clear enough on the "values" part of the dictionary. The values are objects of another type.

Comment: @Oosterman: Then I would pick whatever is cleanest for you as key - when in doubt though I'd prefer the id value - although using the full object might make sense too, there will be additional effort needed though such as overriding equality and `GetHashCode` if necessary

Comment: If I see a `Dictionary<int,OtherClass>` and all I have is a `Foo`, I have to check to make sure I'm picking the right property of the `Foo` object. If I have a `Dictionary<Foo,OtherClass>`, I don't have to guess. Why do you prefer the `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you use as a key has to be able to be compared.  For primitive types, equality is defined generally as you would expect.  For objects, you would be testing reference equality unless you define another way to compare the objects, which you can do by passing the appropriate type of `IComparer` in the `Dictionary` constructor.

In your case, however, keying to the `int` is likely to be simplest.  You would gain no real benefit from using the object as its own key.  You can create the dictionary simply by taking your collection of `Foo` objects and doing something like:

```
IDictionary<int, Foo> fooDictionary = fooCollection.ToDictionary(f => f.ID);
```

Searching the dictionary will be more efficient than simply searching the collection for the given ID each time in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are `Key Value Pairs`. Each Key should be Unique. The Compiler has to make sure the Keys are unique. By Giving the Key as an object instead of an integer, You are probably doing an overkill. The compiler has compare to check the whole object in the Key to make sure it is unique. So i would go for Integer Key if that help you to identify your record uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID - if you already have the object, there's no point in looking it up, too.